# Deedle FillMissing() function bug?

Tags: c#, deedle

I work with Deedle v.1.2.5 on C# and do get strange behavior.

When I replace missing values with `FillMissing(double.NaN)` function, it works as expected, but `FillMissing((x) => double.NaN)` code will not replace missing values.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//unitest
[Test]
public void Missing()
{
    var sb = new SeriesBuilder<int, double>() { { 1, double.NaN }, { 2, 2 } };
    var serie = sb.Series;
    //replaces missing with NaN
    var res = serie.FillMissing(double.NaN);

    //ok
    Assert.AreEqual(double.NaN, res.FirstValue());


    var sb2 = new SeriesBuilder<int, double>() { { 1, double.NaN }, { 2, 2 } };
    var serie2 = sb2.Series;
    //NOT replaces missing with NaN
    var res2 = serie2.FillMissing((x) => double.NaN);

    //crashes
    Assert.AreEqual(double.NaN, res2.FirstValue());
}
```

Comment: This does certainly look like a bug. Just to clarify, what is the error message that you get on the last line?

Comment: @TomasPetricek System.InvalidOperationException: OptionalValue.Value: Value is not available. <- Because it is missing object without value. But actual problem is not consistent behavior of the functions. First function replaces missing object with double.NaN (seems wrong), second - does not.